# bare-metal k8s zone routing for use with Multus cni

Tags: networking, routing, kubernetes, bgp

I have a Kubernetes cluster, every node is located in a different network (different data centers)
So I need to route a public IP address range to this cluster and use those IPv4 addresses within the cluster using Multus CNI as the second network interface for VM pods (KubeVirt).

The first scenario in my mind is creating a virtual network and connecting those nodes to that using a VPN or so on, then running a DHCP server in that network using promiscuous mode and on-link routing.

But, is there any better solution?